# PHP Code showing and not executing?

Tags: php, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code is not being executed (i can see it on source code of page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

I have just installed xampp with all the features(phpmyadmin, mysql, filezilla, apache). The only thing that I cannot get to work is php. I can see the code that's supposed to be running, but it doesn't run. I need detailed step-by-step instructions on how to solve, I have been googling for hours and can't seem to fix this problem, I have tried re-installing the xampp stuff and it's not working! Also, please don't refer me to another forum or website. I am desparate! I am soo close to getting up and running!

Comment: This has been asked so often on so many places. While I understand your frustration, the most logical thing to do would be to direct you to another thread or another website.

Comment: I tried the solution in post 1 and post 2 to no avail

Comment: I found part of the issue: on the status page of the xampp config pages, PHP and MYSQL database(this process is running) claim they are 'deactivated'. How do I activate them? The MySQL database IS running! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WAMP it's also good. 
Also check you server logs

Comment: Ok, I'll give WAMP a shot at it.

Comment: WAMP does the same thing with php, still not working

Comment: FINALLY! I have no idea how it worked, but I am now able to run php scripts!

Answer (score 1):

Try another package like this:
http://www.easyphp.org/

Also install xammp in your main drive like this:
C:/xammp/

Not in program files or anything else.
Also check if apache is running.

Comment: xampp is in C:\xampp; apache is running.